# How to distinguish between negative and minus signs in compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am writing a small PL/0 compiler for practice.

I ran into some problems while writing the expression evaluation part.

Here is a small example:

```
-2 + 1
```

The logic of my program is as below:

1. lexical analysis

   According to the document I found, there is no such thing like 'negative integer' in PL/0, thus `-2` will be parsed as `-` and `2`. The result of this step is: `-`, `2`, `+` and `1`
2. syntax analysis

   I use SLR1 in this step, since the expression is correct, nothing will happen.
3. semantic analysis

   The program will build an *abstract syntax tree* in this step. The principle is simple, an operator stack and an operand stack work together to finish this part. However, the "negative" sign will be treated as a "minus" sign in my code, and I have no good idea to deal with this problem.

Here is a piece of code showing the logic:

```cpp
struct ASTNode {
  ASTNode(char op, int val, ASTNode *left = nullptr, ASTNode *right = nullptr);

  char _op;                   // operator
  int _val;                   // operand
  shared_ptr<ASTNode> _left;  // left child node
  shared_ptr<ASTNode> _right; // right child node
};

void semantic_analyzer::construct_tree(vector<string> &tokens) {
  stack<shared_ptr<ASTNode>> nodeStack;  // operand stack
  stack<char> opStack;                   // operator stack

  // iterate tokens and construct part of the AST
  for (auto &token : tokens) {
    // if the token is a positive integer
    if (str_opekit::is_digit(token)) {
      int val = stoi(token);
      nodeStack.push(make_shared<ASTNode>(' ', val)); // the children will be set as nullptr
    }
    // If the token is a left paren, push it into operator stack
    else if (token == "(") {
      opStack.push('(');
    }
    // If the token is a right paren, pop the operator in the operator stack and calculate result
    else if (token == ")") {
      // Keep popping operators in the operator stack until reach a left paren
      while (opStack.top() != '(') {
        // Pop two operands in the operand stack and construct them into a node
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> right = nodeStack.top();
        nodeStack.pop();
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> left = nodeStack.top();
        nodeStack.pop();
        // Construct a new ASTNode with the two nodes and push into the stack
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> node(new ASTNode(opStack.top(), 0, left, right));
        opStack.pop();
        nodeStack.push(node);
      }
      opStack.pop();  // pop left paren
    }
    // If the token is #, which stands for the end of the expression
    else if (token == "#") {
      break;
    }
    // If the token is an operator, compare its priority with the operator on the top
    // of the stack
    else {
      char op = token[0];
      // while:
      // 1. the operator stack is not empty
      // 2. the operator on the top of the stack is not a left paren
      // 3. the priority of the operator on the top of the stack is higher
      while (!opStack.empty() && opStack.top() != '(' &&
             is_prior(op, opStack.top()) ) {
        // Pop two operands in the stack and construct them into an ASTNode
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> right = nodeStack.top();
        nodeStack.pop();
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> left = nodeStack.top();
        nodeStack.pop();
        // Construct a new ASTNode with the two nodes and push it into the
        // operand stack
        shared_ptr<ASTNode> node =
            make_shared<ASTNode>(opStack.top(), 0, left, right);
        opStack.pop();
        nodeStack.push(node);
      }
      opStack.push(op);
    }
  }

  // Process operators and operands in the stack and construct the tree
  while (!opStack.empty()) {
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> right = nodeStack.top();
    nodeStack.pop();
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> left = nodeStack.top();
    nodeStack.pop();
    shared_ptr<ASTNode> node =
        make_shared<ASTNode>(opStack.top(), 0, left, right);
    opStack.pop();
    nodeStack.push(node);
  }

  this->_root = nodeStack.top();
  nodeStack.pop();
}
```

Since the "negative" sign will be parsed as "minus" sign, not only the result of execution will be wrong, but also the program will call `pop()` on an empty stack, which will cause a crash.

If you need more detailed information about my code, please inform me. Any suggestion is welcomed.

---

The EBNF is from a course I took before. The part associated with the question will be as follows:

1. `letter ::= a|b|...|X|Y|Z`
2. `digit ::= 0|1|...|8|9`
3. `identifier ::= <letter>{<letter>|<digit>}`
4. `unsigned integer ::= <digit>{<digit>}`
5. `factor ::= <identifier>|<unsigned integer>|...`
6. `item ::= <factor>{<multiplying operator><factor>}`
7. `expression ::= [+|-]<item>{<adding operator><item>}`

> '|' stands for "|" in regex
>
> '{...}' stands for "*" in regex
>
> '[...]' stands for "zero or one", having some resemblance to "?" in regex

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have to say I have no such knowledge reserve, could you explain your idea?

Comment: @LiuYuan I think the πάντα ῥεῖ was asking for clarification on whether the issue here is the fact that there's both an unary and a binary version of the `-` operator, at least in C++, both of which have different precedences, see  precedneces 3 and 6 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: *there is no such thing like 'negative integer' in PL/0* -- Then `-2 + 1` is a syntax error?  If not, what is the meaning of `-2 + 1`?  If it is a syntax error, why are you not treating it as such in your parser?  Do the grammar rules of PL/0 allow the unary minus?

Comment: How do ou do the parsing? Do you have a grammar?

Comment: Also, reusing a symbol to mean different things is used by so many computer languages.  For example `&` has multiple meanings in C++.  So what you are asking is something you should have prepared for.

Comment: if you have state, a `parseNumber` would treat `-` as negative number, whereas parseExpr would be something like `parseNumber() parseOp() parseExpr()`.

Comment: LLVM has a "how to write your own programming language" tutorial, where it takes you step-by-step on how to make a (toy) programming language called [Kaleidoscope](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html).

Comment: @fabian The document I got said nothing about the operator precedence, the ENBF in the document is updated in the question. I guess if I want to use such syntax in the program, the operator precedence is necessary, what should I do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie According to the ENBF I updated in the question, the grammar rules allow unary minus, please check my update

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I have a ENBF from a document from a course I took before, please check my updates. If you need more ENBF, please tell me.

Comment: @Jarod42 I do use a finite-state machine in SLR1, but I only used it to check whether the syntax is valid. In the next step, I have no such thing. How should I determine `- 2` is another number minus 2 or a negative 2?

Comment: @Eljay Thanks a lot! I had read that it was possible to use LLVM to write my own language, but I wanted to try to implement a compiler my own way. It turned out there were some technical issues. Thank you very much for your information

Comment: You want to distinguish the unary minus from the binary minus. Your parsing algorithm (a variant of shunting yard if I'm not mistaken) cannot do that easily. You need to either choose a different algorithm, or modify yours to remember a preceding token. For example, in a typical language a minus sign is a unary minus if it is at the beginning of an expression, after an opening parenthesis/bracket, or after another operator, otherwise it is a binary minus, so you can take an advantage of that. A recursive-descent or a LALR parser would do it automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "since the expression is correct, nothing will happen"? Surely, something needs to happen - the parser needs to produce a result (usually an abstract syntax tree).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you for your suggestion! In fact, I am using SLR1 in my code. I am using it for semantic analysis at present, I am starting to think I can perhaps combine the syntax validation check and ensuring whether the minus sign is a unary or binary operator

Comment: @sepp2k I mean the semantic analysis only check whether there are syntax error in the expression. And since the expression meets the requirements of the ENBF, the program will not throw any exception or stop. The abstract semantic tree will be generated in the next step. I guess you mean that I should check the syntax and generate the tree in the same step?

Comment: SLR(1) parser would do it too. I'm not sure how you use it only for semantic analysis. I would say that checking the syntax and generating the tree in the same step is normal and expected.

Comment: @LiuYuan What is an "abstract *semantic* tree"? The syntactic analysis (aka the parser) should produce an abstract *syntax* tree as its output. The semantic analysis should then take this tree as its input.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry for the mistake. My lexical parser(I guess, which is your "*syntactic analysis*") will only distinguish tokens as reserved words, identifiers, operators, or positive integers. The abstract syntax tree will be constructed later, after the semantic analysis, to be more specifically.

Comment: @LiuYuan You have it backward. The order should be: 1. lexical analysis (gives tokens); 2. syntax analysis (gives a syntax tree); 3. semantic analysis. It would be really surprised if your text book gave a different order.

Comment: @LiuYuan But that makes no sense. If the parser produces no tree, then everything coming after the parser needs to redo the parser's work. Like, the parser already has to figure out whether something is a prefix or infix operator, so why have the semantic analysis try to figure out the same thing again?

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, you're right, there is a big problem in the order. Thank you for pointing out that

Comment: @j6t Thanks a lot, I'll check my textbook and notes and rebuild my code in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parser must build the AST of e.g. expressions, consisting of other expressions and operators (items).

The `-` operator can exist in both

- **prefix position** (as a prefix operator) before an `expression` and in
- **infix position**, between two `expression`s.

When your parser parses the first, `-` token, it must check if it can or cannot exist in a *prefix position*, and parse it (emit a **prefix AST node** with operator and expression) or generate an error. If your parser detects a `-` token in an *infix position*, it must check if the token can be in infix position, and generate an **infix AST node** with both `left` and `right` expressions and the `operator`.

Answer (score 1):

The parser must note down every element of the input that it parses. For example, when it sees an `expression`, it must tell the later stages whether there was just a single `item`, or whether there were more than one `item`s with intervening `adding operator`s and which `adding operator`s that were. (Most likely, the parse does so by building a syntax tree.)

At the same time, the parse can also note whether it saw a `+`, a `-` or none of them before the first `item`. It's as simple as that.